# Dynamically loaded chart data not showing Chartjs React

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I created a pie chart that shows the pokemon catch rate. The console.logs all work at first but then it appears to continue running so the data is no longer displaying correctly. The props value is a useState variable from a different component.

Here is my code:

```
const [captureRate, setCaptureRate] = useState();
// const [lossRate, setLossRate] = useState();

console.log("run");



    let capture=[];
    let notCapture=0;
    console.log((props.nameForRate));

    useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/'+(props.nameForRate)+'/')
    .then((res)=>{

      let data=res.data;

      capture[0] = data.capture_rate;
      capture[1] = 255 - (data.capture_rate);
    
      console.log(("it works " +capture));
      setCaptureRate(capture);

    });

    
    console.log("here it is again " + captureRate[0]);
    
  
   }, []);




return(
    <>
    <div className="componentInteriorDoughnut">
          {/* <h3>Chart 2: Doughnut Chart</h3> */}

          <div className="CaptureRate">
          <Doughnut 
          data={{
             
              labels: ['Captured', 'Not Captured'],
              datasets: [{
                  label: 'Capture Rate',
                  data: captureRate,
                  backgroundColor: [
                    'rgb(42, 157, 143)',
                    '#f1f1f1',
                   
                  ],
                
                  borderWidth: 0,
                //   borderRadius:10,
                  
            
                  
                  
              },
```

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you meant with it appears to continue running, what exactly is happening?

Comment: In the console, you see the console.log appear initially but then it changes to undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try adding listener to specific value change, this function will invoke on every state changes. instead of below code

```
useEffect(() => {},[])
```

Instead of that if you can specify which variable to listen, then multiple function call can be avoidable.
For example use like this

```
useEffect(() => {},[notCapture]);
```

In this scenario if there is any change happens to notCaputure variable, then only function got triggered

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code. It may help you.

```
const finalData = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const data = {
                labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'My First dataset',
                    data: actionsListData.map(({ EditorId }) => EditorId)
                }]
            }
            resolve(data)
        })
    }

<ChartControl
            type={ChartType.Bar}
            datapromise={finalData()}
        />
```

Please refer below link for details

https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/ChartControl/